# Select list population based off of other select list

Tags: c#, sql, lambda, asp.net-core

I'm in a bit of a pickle rick and I need some help. Below is the code for my select lists in a form. I need the certification list to populate based off of what category they pick from the category list. How do I get this to work?

CODE:

```
// GET: INT_CertificationsXREF/Create
public IActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.FullName = UserInformation.Globals.FullName;
    ViewData["INT_CertificationCategoriesID"] = new SelectList(_context.INT_CertificationCategories, "ID", "Category");
    ViewData["INT_CertificationConferredID"] = new SelectList(_context.INT_CertificationConferred, "ID", "ConferredBy");
    ViewData["INT_CertificationsID"] = new SelectList(_context.INT_Certifications, "ID", "Certification").Where(i => i.CategoryID = ViewData["INT_CertificationCategoriesID"]);
    ViewData["RIM_ResourceID"] = new SelectList(_context.RIM_Resource, "ID", "FirstName");
    return View();
}
```

Comment: You can't unless you are passing that Category ID.  Right now you're just in the get and it doesn't pass any parameters. You may have to do an AJAX request to populate your certifications. Also, PICKLE RICK!

Comment: Search for "Cascading DropDownList" and you will find a lot of information on this concept.  The idea is that you start with a group of selects with only one populated to begin with, then make AJAX calls based on selection to populate subsequent lists

Comment: this may give you some ideas https://www.cloudscribe.com/docs/easy-cascading-dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

you can filter the list A with the list B using the function **Contains**

```
ViewData["INT_CertificationCategoriesID"] = new SelectList(_context.INT_CertificationCategories, "ID", "Category");
    ViewData["INT_CertificationConferredID"] = new SelectList(_context.INT_CertificationConferred, "ID", "ConferredBy");
    ViewData["INT_CertificationsID"] = new SelectList(_context.INT_Certifications, "ID", "Certification").Where(i => i.CategoryID.Contains(_context.INT_CertificationCategories.ID));
    ViewData["RIM_ResourceID"] = new SelectList(_context.RIM_Resource, "ID", "FirstName");
```